# Why does main method in Java always need arguments?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Why does the main method in Java always need arguments? Why should we write `String[] args` every time, instead of just writing it when we use any arguments?

A method like this generates `Main method not found` compiler error. Since we never use any arguments to the main method, this should be allowed.

```
public static void main()
{
}
```

This is not an interview question. It just came to my mind while programming.

Comment: C inheritance. You could use `main(String... args)` so you might call `main()` but that isn't your question.

Comment: By the way, JAVA is not acronym. They(Sun) named the language after the coffee Java. Though some people retrofit acronym to Java, e.g. Just Another Vague Acronym

Comment: It will compile but will give runtime error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Basically, there are four answers:

1. Because that's the way it was designed.  Yea, I know that's a circular reason.  But the point is that this is the way it is and it ain't going to change.  So unless you are planning on designing your own language, the question is moot.
2. Cleanness of design (aka the DRY principle).  Don't specify two entry point signatures when one can do the job.  And clearly, it can.
3. Semantic simplicity.  Suppose (hypothetically) that Java *did* support both `void main(String[])` and `void main()` entry points.  What would happen if a class defined both methods?  Is that an error?  If not, which one takes precedence when there is ambiguity?  Is this confusing yet?

   By only recognizing `void main(String[])`, the JLS avoids that problem<sup>1</sup>.
4. This is analogous to the standard C and C++ entrypoint signatures.  (Admittedly, some C / C++ runtimes support other non-standard entrypoints as well, but that's not exactly a good thing<sup>2</sup>.)

None of this means that it would have been unambiguously wrong to do it another way.  And for example C# gives you alternative signatures, and deals with the ambiguity problem by requiring the developer to designate an entry point some other way.

FWIW, [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) describes the "main" method in a number of languages.

---

<sup>1 - Though then you have the "problem" that people who are new to Java might *guess* (incorrectly) that multiple entry points ought to work, try it, and get a surprise.  But I don't think any design could cope with "programming by guesswork".


2 - For a start, it is a portability issue.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Because the `java` tool that runs the application looks for a `main` with a specific signature, so it knows it's calling the right one. Java has method overloading, so when looking up a method, you have to specify a fairly complete signature. Granted the `java` tool could do something more complex (look for the specific signature and, not having found it, look for any `main` and call it if it only finds one), but that's not what the Java designers decided to do (and *subjectively*, FWIW, I think that's for the best — keep it simple).

You can find the details in the Java Language Specification, [Chapter 12: Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html). And note that as of when Java got variable argument lists, it became possible to declare `main` in two different ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
// or
public static void main(String... args)
```

Comment: Yeah, but why main method without any argument is not allowed. In C or C++ we can or cannot include arguments in the main method. But why not in JAVA

Comment: @AndroidDecoded: Because Java has method overloading and the `java` tool looks specifically for the `main` defined by the JLS. I've expanded the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As JVM starts executing the java program it searches for the main method having this signature(i.e String array)

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way they designed it. Corollary to that, you might ask why its cousin(C#) allows Main method with or without parameters, it's just the way they designed it.

There's no serious rationale there, each language designers have their preferences what principles you should subscribe to. Sometimes that's for us to infer, or adhere to(sometimes we cannot get things our way) for the meantime.

Hmm... this reminds me of the OS I'm using now. Prior to OS X Lion, you can only resize at right bottom corner of the window. That's 28+ years of waiting before they finally put the capability to resize at any window's corners on their OS.

Even I like Mac OS too much, I would not go out to defend their stance before that a window should be resizable on one corner only. Zealotry is one thing, but blind adherence is another.

So it is good thing you are practicing critical thinking and not blindly believing that Java's main method signature is **the only right way**

---

A digression, waiting for Mac to have resizable edges at any corner is akin to me waiting for Java to have first-class property. Despite the JSON name(**Java**Script Object Notation, though of course Javascript is not Java), C# object initializer(via its property initializer and collection initializer) has more affinity with JSON as compared to Java object initializer with JSON. C# object initializer is very neat and closely resemble JSON.

C#

```
var p = new {
    Lastname = "Lennon",
    Firstname = "John",
    PlacesBeen = 
        new[]
        {
            new { City = "Liverpool", Country = "England" },
            new { City = "New York", Country = "US" },
            new { City = "Tokyo", Country = "Japan" }
        }
};

return Json(p);
```

Javascript:

```
var p = {
    "Lastname" : "Lennon",
    "Firstname" : "John",
    "PlacesBeen" :             
        [
            { "City" : "Liverpool", "Country" : "England" },
            { "City" : "New York", "Country" : "US" },
            { "City" : "Tokyo", "Country" : "Japan" }
        ]
};
```

Consequently, with C#'s first-class property(not shoehorned to method) and collection initializer, not only the code become concise and neat, it now closely resemble what most developers are using now for data interchange format, i.e. JSON.

Java's object initializer syntax is far removed from JSON style. I will not defend Java's design decision(e.g. property syntax/design) on this regard :-)

So there, in the same vein that I will not defend Java language designer's design decision on Java's property syntax/design, I will not defend `public static void main(String[] args)` ツ

Comment: Yeah, But JAVA should also allow such main method. Since I don't know C# I can't refer to this example.

Comment: @AndroidDecoded An example could be tried at http://ideone.com  C# without argument: http://ideone.com/rS1pk C# with argument: http://ideone.com/3lQjd

Comment: Like you, I believe there's no reason why parameter-less main method should not be allowed in Java. It could be allowed, just look at other languages. We should not look at some things in a technical manner, sometimes we should look at their overriding principles

Answer (score -1):

when you are trying to run a java program, JVM will search the main method with **String array** as argument to start the execution of the program from there. As the method you are given is not with that signature, so it will raise an exception **No main method found**

Answer (score -1):

I think Java "copied" this habit from c/c++, and hard coded in java.c :

```
  /* Get the application's main method */
  mainID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mainClass, "main",
                                     "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  if (mainID == NULL) {
      if ((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
          ReportExceptionDescription(env);
      } else {
        message = "No main method found in specified class.";
        messageDest = JNI_TRUE;
      }
      goto leave;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

java is designed in this way. if we donot write string args[] ,then program will get compiled 
but it will not run.

Answer (score -1):

its may be as most of the inputs come from outside the main() like from command line arguments,so to catch these values it has String[]args signature.