# What are the input arguments taken by my main method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Consider the following Class.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length);       // out put 0
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args)); // out put []
    }
}
```

Based on this result I thought that there are no arguments taken by `main` method in java. Please correct me if I'm wrong. if it takes some input argument why i am getting this output?

Comment: If you run your program with no arguments, then this is the correct output. `args` is a `String[]` of size 0.

Comment: `if it takes some input argument why i am getting this output?` how does command you used to run this code looks like?

Comment: @Pshemo: It sounds like it's being run without arguments inside an IDE.

Comment: This sound interesting if I run `java Test` mean there are no argument. Then why can't we use `public static void main() {}` as a main method?

Comment: This SO question explains why arguments are needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783190/why-main-method-in-java-always-needs-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always choose to run your program with or without arguments.  If you do not specify any arguments, `args` will be an empty array (as you've demonstrated here).  If you do specify arguments, `args` will contain the list of arguments that were passed.

See Java's documentation on [Command-Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Run it from cmd line like

```
java Test "StringArgument1"
```

and you will get the output: `StringArgument1`

Currently, you're not passing any command line arguments.

Comment: This sound interesting if I run `java Test` mean there are no argument. Then why can't we use `public static void main() {}` as a main method?

Comment: @Ruchira: Look at this link as the exact reason they're needed is listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783190/why-main-method-in-java-always-needs-arguments

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle Docs, example,

Should help you understand better;

User Input:

```
java Echo Drink Hot Java

// Output for the program below:
Drink
Hot
Java

public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notepad, you can provide command line arguments as

`java Test aa bb` .

Not providing any arguments will return a blank set in the list