# Why we Pass String array as argument to main() method, why not any collection type or wrapper type or primitive type?

Tags: java, string, arguments, program-entry-point

why is it mandatory to pass string arg[] as an argument in main method?
why we cannot pass any other data type available in java?
whats the importance of passing String arg[] in main method in java?

Comment: It is the system arguments used to run your application!

Comment: There is a similar question in Stackoverflow. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783190/why-main-method-in-java-always-needs-arguments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

History.  This is a convention since the days of C, maybe even earlier?  Java took most of its syntax from C.

Also, command line arguments are Strings which is why that is the data type.  Collections did not exist in Java 1 so they were not an option.  Arrays did exist.

Answer (score 7):

Because by passing `String arrays`, we can pass all the necessary parameters like options/arguments related to the program in the form of String easily. There can be several parameters!

Also, all the other datatypes can be easily converted from String!

An example of calling a program with several parameters therefore resulting in storage of them in String array!

```
java Sample_Example example1 example2 example3
```

Arguments:

```
  args[0]=example1
  args[1]=example2
  args[2]=example3
```

Here, you are calling `Sample_Example` Class and passing three parameters `example1`,`example2` and `example3` to be used by the program! So, it is always an better alternative to store them in an String array rather than other primitive data-types or in collections or in Wrapper data-types. Always we tend to make our work simpler and here Java makes it simpler for all of us by providing this facility!

Comment: While true, this doesn't explain why they insist on an array, where a single String would also work.

Comment: This thing we can achieve by using any of the collection types also. So, Why main(String arg[]), why not main(List l) or main(Integer i) ?

Comment: I already mentioned that Java tend to make it simpler by using simplest of all data-types ---`String`. Though I agree that Collections too provide that feature but they indeed need a purer OR better way. Like if you don't provide Generic implementation of Collections like `List<String>,etc.` ,it will be a crap as you can store all kind of items in `List` resulting in unstructured data-strucure with no basic-type which is really,really a bad idea! If you are satisfied,please mark an upvote and if extremely satisfied,accept the answer!

Comment: Also, Collections did not exist until Java 1.2.  I'm starting to feel old :-). Yeah, back in Java 1 we had to walk uphill both ways to the interpreter in the snow...

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that your Java application will be invoked via a command (whether explicitly entered by a user, implicitly entered (like when you click a shortcut in your OS's GUI), etc).

The `String[]` refers to the command line arguments specified when your application was invoked.

See [Command-Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) in Oracle's Java tutorials for more details.

Answer (score 1):

when we run a java program to command prompt, we can pass some input to our Java program. Those inputs are stored in this String args array.

Answer (score 1):

Because if also we are not passing any argument value while running the main method then also its working fine. It creates an empty string, when we are not passing any values to string arg[]. Where else in case of other data type we have to pass some values.