# Why do we write "string [] args" in java?

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point

I just want to know in Java programming why do we write **`String args[]`** in `public static void main(String [] args)`.

We have other datatypes also but why String?

Comment: why repeat the text two times? || String because that is the type of what you type at command line - pure text (or because it is specified to be a String array in the Java Language Specification) || BTW you could also use `String... args`, as any other name instead of `args`

Comment: *"We have other datatypes also but why String??"* - Because `String` is the only (immutable) type that can represent all possible values that may be provided by the user on the command line.

Comment: BTW @GURMEET - actually we have to write `String[]` with uppercase `S`, not lowercase as in title :-)

Comment: *Why do we write "String [] args" in java?"* - Because if we don't, the JVM won't recognize the main method as an entry point method. That is how it is specified to work, and has been since Java 1.0. However [JEP 445](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445) will relax this somewhat.  It is currently proposed for Java 21 as a Preview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we Pass String array as argument to main() method, why not any collection type or wrapper type or primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225771/why-we-pass-string-array-as-argument-to-main-method-why-not-any-collection-ty)

Comment: Why String as opposed to what?

Answer (score 3):

Arguments from the command line in most operating systems are received by executing programs as a list or array of strings. In C language this is usually represented by `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Java just has a more convenient type.