# Why it is mandatory to mention "String args[]" in main method & if we print args[] why do we get this as output : "[Ljava.lang.String;@174e5edb"?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(" This is awesome "+args);
    }
}
```

In the above code, why it is mandatory to mention `String args[]` in `main()` and why do we get `"[Ljava.lang.String;@174e5edb"` as output when we print it?

Comment: The other half of your question (not part of the duplicate question) was already asked here: [*Why main method in Java always needs arguments?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10783190/2991525)

Answer (score 1):

> why it is mandatory to mentioned "String args[]" in main()

That's because you could pass parameters to the application at startup which then are the content of that array. As an alternative you could use varargs, i.e. `String... args`.

> why we get "[Ljava.lang.String;@174e5edb" as output when we print it

That's the way the `toString()` method is implemented for arrays (in fact for `Object`). Use `Arrays.toString(args)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `main` method is simply defined the way it is. The `String[]` is used to pass parameters to the program. `"[Ljava.lang.String;@174e5edb"` is the type of the value, which is `String[]` (`"[Ljava.lang.String"`). Followed by the position in the heap (`"@174..."`). This is the default way of representing objects in java. If you want to print the content of the array, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));`.