# Why args are compulsory for main

Tags: scala

If I use like below considering I don't need to take arguments, it doesn't detect for Scala in eclipse.

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(): Unit = {
    println("Hello Scala!!!")
  }
}
```

It works fine with `args: Array[String]`

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello Scala!!!")
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783190/why-does-main-method-in-java-always-need-arguments

Comment: Define "compulsory"; You can *have* an arg-less `main`, it just won't be considered an entry point. (Scala may insist on a single main method with the conventional args; I don't know. But it wouldn't be an entry point without the args.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it's simply a convention on the JVM. You won't be able to invoke your object as entry point when running your program. For example, in Scala.js you have [`main()` without arguments](http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/).

If you don't need the arguments you can [mixin the `App` trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667630/difference-between-using-app-trait-and-main-method-in-scala):

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello Scala!!!")
}
```

Comment: you can still get arguments with the App trait: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11667630/217324

Comment: @NathanHughes yes that is correct. They are available through value `args` as before.

Comment: Thanks & Great to know. Tutorial I was following mentioned that you don't have to write all what JVM requires Scala will compile for you. I guess it is true in this case also :)

Comment: Worth adding, `def main(args: Array[String]): Int = ???` will warn and isn't runnable from IDE, but `scala` runner will run it. It would be nice if the scala runner relaxed more such conventions. I'd like to `def main(args: String*)` for instance and have the runner just use it, even if Java-oriented launchers balk.