# Cannot Run Class Files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, program-entry-point, intellij-14

Notice that the run option for the main class is greyed out. I tried restarting intelliJ, rebuilding, cleaning, everything.

[image]
(click to zoom in)

Comment: Your main method is incorrect. Java expects main to handle potential arguments which is passed in form of String[] array.

Comment: Related: [Why does main method in Java always need arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10783190)

Comment: Interesting, I always thought the `main` method parameters were optional unless needed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method requires a String array or varargs argument to be picked up.

Comment: Thanks! I had to wait a few a minutes for intelliJ to pick up the new `main` method so I thought it didn't work.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

Move your code inside of the src folder. Once it's there, it'll be compiled on-the-fly every time it's saved.

IntelliJ only recognizes files in specific locations as part of the project - namely, anything inside of a blue folder is specifically considered to be source code.

Also - while I can't see all of your source code - be sure that it's proper Java syntax, with a class declared the same as the file and that it has a main method (specifically public static void main(String[] args)). IntelliJ won't run code without a main method (rather, it can't - neither it nor Java would know where to start).

Use

```
public static void main(String[] args))
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your main() method, from:

```
public static void main() {...}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```